# How to uninstall cluster from win2k8 machine?

Tags: cluster

I have installed the cluster on a w2k8 machine, but my cluster nodes are not showing in the machine. I want to remove the cluster reinstall -- how can I remove the cluster from the win2k8 machine? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Serverfault or the other one, not here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to command propt and run the following command:

```
 cluster node <node name> /forcecleanup

 Ex: suppose ur node1 name is testnode1 then the command should be 

 cluster node testnode1 /forcecleanup
```